Queries related to DevOps
I have certain queries regarding DevOps and automated testing:
Q1. What are the most experienced challenges while using automated testing in the ci/cd pipeline?
Q2. What are the different strategies to overcome those challenges?
Q3.Who decides and is responsible for managing different environments in CI/CD pipeline, such as STAGING, TESTING, and PRODUCTION?
expecting a great views and answers about my queries for better understanding.
